# C++ Passing a class method as function pointer

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I have a class that has to process data from various files. I thought about creating one function that will read the specified file and then also accept a call back so that it can use that to process the line. Below is an example class to represent what I am trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


class Example
{
    std::vector<std::string> m_exampleFileData {
        "test1",
        "test2",
        "test3"
    };

public:

    void doSomethingMain(const std::string& path)
    {        
        processFile(path, doSomething);
    }


private:    
    void processFile(const std::string& filePath, void (Example::*fpProcessLine)(const std::string&) )
    { 
        for (const auto& line : m_exampleFileData) {    
            this->*fpProcessLine(line);
        }
    }

    void doSomething(const std::string& line)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello: " << line << '\n';
    }

};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {    
    const std::string filePath{"path"};
    Example ex;

    ex.doSomethingMain(filePath);
}
```

Compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/LKoXSZ

The main issue is that no matter what I do I can't seem to be able to pass the function properly to `processFile`. Is there a way to do this in C++? How do I go about this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to spell things out explicitly, in this situation:

```
    processFile(path, &Example::doSomething);
```

Furthermore, you also need to slap on an extra pair of parenthesis, due to operator precedence:

```
         (this->*fpProcessLine)(line);
```

Comment: But will that bind to the instance? That seems to bind to the class.. or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, of course it "binds to the class". A method pointer is not bound to any specific class, that's what makes it a method pointer. It's the`(this->*fpProcessLine)` part which binds the method pointer to a specific class instance, in this case being `this`.

Comment: A bit harsh... but ok. This is not how I see this done in other languages, hence the confusion...

Comment: Many core C++ features have no equivalent in other contemporary programming languages; and I often give this advice to anyone coming from a Java background: forget everything you know. Despite the deceptively similar syntax, C++ is different, fundamentally, at its very core and if you try to draw analogies with what you know about Java, you'll be perpetually confused when C++ does not work the way you expect it to work.